# How to get artist pictures from mp3 in android

Tags: android

How to get artist pictures from mp3 in android??

I Successed get Album Art from mp3 but I Don't know get Artist Pictures

Comment: I believe mp3 can contain only one picture - album cover. If you compare it to some online streaming service where they show both album and artist, i think they looking by name in their DB. If you really want, try to get artist name and make some rest request to any service with covers (maybe last.fm or smt).

Comment: What are artist pictures? I do not believe that is stored in MP3 files

Comment: I think Taek want to get that picture: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/11/21/0031/0876/2044780/80/5df380a09b.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that library [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic) to read and edit mp3 tags

Comment: I will try this .Thank you !